# how to retrieve check box value form database in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a city table contains all cities.when user sign up all area coming from this in the form of check boxes.user can select multipule cities by checkbox.I want when user edit their profile area come with again in the from of checkbox along with checked check box which he selected at the time of signup and other cities checkbox unchecked

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

var op = document.getElementById("checkboxid");
                var abc = op.options[op.selectedIndex].value;

This helpful for retrieve the check box value